# What is wrong in this example with Heisenberg principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, nanoscience

On Heisenberg principle

Suppose an electron is beamed in a nanotube with (width $\Delta x$) on which has been applied a negative voltage so the walls are repealing the electron and it can not approach them. It must travel down the tube with absolutely constant velocity e.g. the spread of $v$ is 0 ($\Delta v=0$). Then it follows $\Delta x\cdot \Delta v=0$ which contradicts Heisenberg principle.
What do you think is wrong here?

Comment: What? You just broke the HUP by imposing $\Delta \textbf{v}=0$ for no apparent reason. The HUP clearly implies that this is impossible (unless you'd somehow have an infinite $\Delta x$ I guess). You just assumed the contradiction yourself for no particular reason, as far as I can tell

Comment: There is no particular reason for v to change as is implied by the Newton laws. How do you imagine will the electron move inside the tube?

Comment: If you are using newton's laws to analyze a quantum problem, there lies your issue. If newtonian mechanics applied to quantum objects, we wouldn't waste our precious young years learning.... quantum mechanics ;)

Comment: To answer what you added in your comment,  I don't imagine the electron moving in the tube and neither should you. Trajectories are not well-defined in QM. In general, if you start trying to "picture" stuff too literally in QM, you're headed for a world of pain

Comment: So according to QM the electron does what?

Comment: The wavefunction of the electron propagates according to Schrodinger equation and the spread in position and momentum can be obtained from it at all times. I think you need to learn the basics of QM before asking questions on the matter. Unfortunately, we can not teach you here the elementary knowledge that you need to grasp the answers. If you try to ask questions without any prior fundamental understanding, it will only raise more questions in a never-ending cycle. There are many good textbooks if you wanna learn :)

Comment: @BarbaudJulien Please use an answer to answer the question. The comments are not the place to discuss the answer to the question.

Comment: Originally, I thought mercury might have a reason to set deltav to 0 that he didn't mention and I just wanted to check that. Mercury has read the content anyway, and the content has already been incorporated in existing answers.

Comment: @BarbaudJulien who are you to tell people here what to ask and what not? You are an extremely arrogant creature and some sort of scientific fascist. What you know is just to repeat old cliches and thinking is definitely not your strong side. That's the main reason you indulge people. You don't know what else to do. Prepare: the fate of such creatures is harsh! Infrn is awaiting you.

Comment: I am shaking in excitement for whatever infrn is. Given the requirements to get in there it sounds like a VIP place I am going to thoroughly enjoy. Seeing from the upvotes that that a few people agreed with my fascist comments, I will also be in good company with creatures alike, yay!

Answer (score 1):

For a start, you have only constrained the position of the electron in two dimensions- you do not know where it is along the axis of travel.

You also, as a commenter has pointed out, simply assumed the uncertainty in velocity is zero, which means that you are treating the electron as a classical point-like particle with an unambiguous position and trajectory. That is wrong. The quantum mechanical description is that the electron has an associated wave function which in a general state will be some form of wave packet that does not have a single frequency, but instead a spread of frequencies is present. While the group velocity of the wave packet may be known, the individual components of the packet are moving at different speeds, and it is that spread of speeds that counts in the HUP.

Comment: That would be better suited as a comment in my opinion. Additionally, OP made (unjustified) assumptions about the velocity, not the position

Comment: I appreciate your viewpoint. However, the OP specifically asked 'what is wrong here?' and I specifically answered.

Comment: I disagree with the fact that this points out what is wrong with OP's question. What is wrong with it it that he assumes $\Delta v =0$ out of the blue. I don't see that when I read you answer

Comment: Ah, but I said 'for a start', meaning that I was presenting merely one of the fatal flaws in his reasoning. You had already mentioned the other.

Comment: That's why I would see it as a comment rather than an answer. But it's fine, just my opinion

Comment: @BarbaudJulien Even incomplete answers should be posted as answers, not comments. Comments are rather for requesting clarification or suggesting improvements.

Comment: @J. Murray Noted! The answer also has been expanded after the comments and is now quite extensive anyway

Answer (score 0):

The Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle applies independently to each spatial dimension:
\begin{align}
\Delta x \: \Delta p_x & \gtrsim \hbar/2, \\
\Delta y \: \Delta p_y & \gtrsim \hbar/2.
\end{align}
This means that if your nanotube is oriented along $x$, so that the motion is confined along $x$ but not along $y$, the two constraints can look very different.

- If $x$ is constrained within the nanotube width $w$, then the transverse momentum must be nonzero, and bounded below by $\Delta p_x \gtrsim\frac{\hbar}{2w}$.
- For the longitudinal coordinate, $y$, there are no remaining constraints $-$ it behaves exactly like a free particle.

  In particular, you claim that

  > It must travel down the tube with absolutely constant velocity e.g. the spread of $v$ is 0 ($\Delta v=0$)

  but, to be clear, there is *no* requirement that this be the case. The uncertainty in $p$ is independent of whether it changes in time, and it is perfectly possible to have a nonzero spread of velocity.

  What you get, in the general case, is the standard Heisenberg uncertainty inequality, $\Delta y \: \Delta p_y \gtrsim \hbar/2$, and you can have cases with very small $\Delta p_y$ (including arbitrarily small and approaching zero), in which case the Heisenberg principle tells you that the particle position uncertainty must be very large (in the direction *along* the nanotube). But you can also have cases where the particle is localized to a smallish region along the nanotube ($\Delta y$ is not big), in which case the Heisenberg principle tells you that $\Delta p_y$ must be bigger, which implies that if you let the particle propagate then it will spread over a larger region and $\Delta y$ will eventually become big.

Comment: For a case of a tube with width dx the HUP gives dp as you write it. But in my case there is voltage applied and it absorbs (kind of) the movement in that direction. Like when you apply negative voltage to a cube and the negative charge (with little kinetic energy) will gather in the center. So maybe this voltage reduces dp (this might not be in contradiction to HUP as it is a complementary condition).

Comment: As it goes to longitudinal component - let assume one has a plane wave with well defined v. It falls on many tubes and gets in one of them. So at the entrance the velocity is well defined. But v is bound to p and E kinetic which are both conserved even in QM. So I don't get how v could change and not brake E and p conservation laws. Do you understand? About the reasoning that the electron can be anywhere along the tube at any time if dv=0 in my opinion this breaks the speed of light barrier. Don't it?

Comment: @Mercury Momentum conservation holds whenever the hamiltonian is invariant under spatial translations; if your nanotube has an entrance, then this invariance is not present and momentum conservation is not present. (If you want to introduce it, then you need to include the centre of mass of the nanotube as a dynamical variable.)

Comment: Energy conservation does hold in this setting (the hamiltonian is time-translation invariant) but if you want a state with well-defined energy then you're talking about the scattering states of the nanotubes, which have no requirement to have a well-defined momentum.

Comment: Generally, you seem to be switching back-and-forth between classical and quantum mechanics throughout. This is a recipe for a mistake. Either you're thinking in terms of wavefunctions *throughout*, or you're doing classical physics.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever happens is described by the Schrodinger equation and any Schrodinger eave function obeys the uncertainty principle.

Comment: Of course one can complicate things and try to solve Schroedinger equation. Then it is obvious that the wavefunction would be zero inside a tube where negative potential is applied on it. But it is obvious with simple classical reasoning. But maybe a photon can knock out an electron inside with impulse along the tube.

Comment: @Mercury Solving Schrodinger's equation does not complicate things. It prevents oversimplification and incorrect statements.

Answer (score -1):

You constrained the position of the electron along the width of the tube, with the situation you described there is no reason this should have any effect on the momentum of the particle along the direction of travel. The position constraint you have given just implies that the radial momentum of the electron in the tube will have a wide distribution if $\Delta x$ is small.

On the other hand if you just assume $\Delta v=0$ along the length of the tube, then first off you need an infinitely long tube, and the electron is fully delocalized ($\Delta x=\infty$) along the length of the tube. A way to imagine this situation is to see the electron as a sort of standing wave in the tube. Nevertheless, as Barbaud Julien pointed out, there is no reason to just suppose your electron is in a momentum eigenstate (i.e. $\Delta v=0$) and in all reasonable physical situations it just isn't.

Comment: Note that the potential applied to the tube prevents the electron moving in x direction. So in horizontal direction dv must be 0 (or very small). If there was no voltage applied v would spread after entering according to Heisenberg principle and hit the walls eventually absorbed therein.

Comment: @Mercury If you just keep applying classical reasoning to a quantum problem, you're just going to end up with a classical picture in which the HUP simply does not hold. Write down a Hamiltonian for your system and do the calculations.

Comment: Along the length of the tube the electron enters with some v (one can have a plane wave and it enters in the tube accidentally) and as nothing acts on it in that direction the energy and momentum conservation would be broken if it has huge uncertainty. If as you write there is a standing wave in the tube build up immediately how can you get rid of superluminal velocity?

Comment: Looks out like SHUT UP AND CALCULATE.

Comment: @Mercury you can afford to reason without calculating only if you would be able to do the calculation if you wanted to.

Comment: The case has been regarded about 20 years ago. I needed help to understand what it is. It is the case of a triangle potential well which I found solved in an article from 2003. It is pointless to calculate things already calculated. The case is not trivial.

Answer (score -4):

The proposed scheme can never happen because of a trivial reason which is outside QM. The electron can not get into a nanotube on which a negative voltage is applied due to the classical repealing forces. So the Heisenberg principle is saved for great relief of some physicists.